# Whats wrong with this MySQL Update Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

1st I'll give you the query, and then I'll tell you what I am trying to achieve, as I could be soo wrong or soo close.

```
       mysql_query("UPDATE link_building SET 
ID=$ID,Site=$Site,Date=$Date,Target_Site=$Target_Site,
        Target_Contact_Email=$Target_Contact_Email,
    Target_Contact_Name=$Target_Contact_Name,
        Link_Type=$Link_Type,Link_Acquired=$Link_Acquired,
    Notes=$Notes,Link_URL=$Link_URL WHERE ID=" . $ID);
```

What am I trying to achieve?
I want to update the fields

```
("ID","Site","Date","Target_Site","Target_Contact_Email","Target_Contact_Name",
    "Link_Type","Link_Acquired","Notes","Link_URL")
```

in the table link_building with the values stored in the variables

```
    ("$ID","$Site","$Date","$Target_Site","$Target_Contact_Email","$Target_Contact_Name",
"$Link_Type","$Link_Acquired","$Notes","$Link_URL")
```

But I only want to update the record whos Id is equal to $ID.

UPDATE: I DO NOT SEE ANY ERROR. ITS REDIRECTS TO link_building.php and displays success message but doesn't change the data in the MySQL table.

Comment: Are you seeing an error?  If so, please post it in your question.

Comment: You didn't say what happens that shouldn't, but I'm going to take a guess: you're not escaping your variables, that's what's wrong with it. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php (In the long run, learning to use PDO would bypass this problem altogether: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php )

Comment: Whats the point of looking for a value with a specific 'ID' which you just set?

Comment: Other than the fact that you don't have quotes around your values in your query, it looks correct to me.  What error(s) are you getitng?

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk: It's the other way around: the query first looks up the ID, *then* sets it (so it's possible to change it). Of course, if the OP is not looking to change it (as it looks here), it is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the data and removing the update of the ID since its already in your conditions:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE link_building SET Site='".mysql_real_escape_string($Site)."',Date='".mysql_real_escape_string($Date)."',Target_Site='".mysql_real_escape_string($Target_Site)."', Target_Contact_Email='".mysql_real_escape_string($Target_Contact_Email)."', Target_Contact_Name='".mysql_real_escape_string($Target_Contact_Name)."', Link_Type='".mysql_real_escape_string($Link_Type)."',Link_Acquired='".mysql_real_escape_string($Link_Acquired)."', Notes='".mysql_real_escape_string($Notes)."',Link_URL='".mysql_real_escape_string($Link_URL)."' WHERE ID=" . intval($ID));
```

Comment: Additionally, you would likely want to mysql_real_escape_string($var) each of those variables.

Answer (score 2):

if your columns are named like `Target Site` (with a space in it), you should adress it like that in your query (wich will force you to add backticks to it). also, you'll have to add quotes to colums that store anything else that strings. your query should look like:

```
UPDATE
  link_building
SET 
  ID = $ID,
  Site = '$Site',                   // single quotes for values
  Date = '$Date',                   // ...
  ´Target Site´ = '$Target_Site'    // and ´ for fields
  [...]
```

this should solve why the query doesn't work (in addition: not how a bit or formatting makes it *much* more readable).

you havn't given information about that, but please note that you should always sanitize your variables before using it (your code doesn't look like you do) to avoid sql-injections. you can do this using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or, even better, start using [prepared statements](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 2):

For one, you're forgetting that you still need to quote your strings;

```
mysql_query("UPDATE link_building SET Site='$Site', Date='$Date',".  
            "Target_Site='$Target_Site', Target_Contact_Email='$Target_Contact_Email',".
            "Target_Contact_Name='$Target_Contact_Name', Link_Type='$Link_Type',".
            "Link_Acquired='$Link_Acquired', Notes='$Notes', Link_URL='$Link_URL' ".
            "WHERE ID=$ID");
```

Note the added `'`s around all strings.

Bonus remark; you should really be using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on your strings before passing them on to the database.